# How to make this Oracle select statement perform faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, query-performance

Could any please advise on how to make this query perform faster than it is at the moment?

```
T2.ADI is indexed on TABLE2 
T1.ADI is indexed on TABLE1
T1.RC AND T1.BEG_DT_TM  is composite indexed on TABLE1
```

Is there  anything else I could do to make it faster?

```
SELECT T1.ASI, T1.RC, T1.BEG_DT_TM
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 
    ON T2.ADI = T1.ADI 
    AND T2.END_DT_TM > T1.BEG_DT_TM 
    AND T2.BEG_DT_TM <= T1.END_DT_TM
WHERE T1.RC IN (12345, 56764460, 49862, 375723)
  AND T1.BEG_DT_TM >= 
  AND T1.BEG_DT_TM <= 
  AND T1.END_DT_TM >= 
  AND T1.END_DT_TM <=
```

Here is the explain plan:
[image]

Comment: I assume you ran an Explain Plan to see where most of the time is spent. Can you show us here? Then - are statistics up to date? In any case, the join conditions will make the query slow regardless of anything else.

Comment: thanks @mathguy i have attached the explain plan in my update above

Comment: What is this "  AND T1.BEG_DT_TM >=  " ?  Missing right side of condition.  What does "faster" mean?  How long does it take?  How many rows are in the tables and result set?

Comment: thanks @OldProgrammer faster means I want to reduce how long it takes to return rows. At the moment it takes around 13seconds to return 15,000 rows if the query is not cached by running alter system flush shared_pool; and alter system flush buffer_cache;

Comment: Thats a lot of data to return.  Since we don't know how this query is being executed, ( what library, programming environment?) There is no way to determine what portion of that time is spent executing the query vs returning the results to the host environment.   You will need to run a [Trace and tkprof](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL793) to get further details.

Comment: A SQL Monitor report will show you where time is being spent, together with estimated and actual cardinalities. Getting good cardinality estimates are instrumental in getting good execution plans and hence good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Put [covering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index) indexes on both tables:

```
create index t1_c_1 on TABLE1(RC, BEG_DT_TM, END_DT_TM, ADI, ASI);
create index t2_c_1 on TABLE2(ADI, BEG_DT_TM, END_DT_TM);
```

These indexes are created with the columns in the most optimal order for the query, plus they include other non-join columns found in the select list, so index-only access can be used (avoiding any need to access the actual table).